# Execute a different command depending on the output of the previous

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying out something which is quite simple, yet I can't find an answer or rather can't figure out how to ask the question on Google.
So I thought it would be better to just show what I'm doing with pictures, here.

Here is the script I'm working on:

[image: screenshot]

What it does is simple: get all virtual machines depending on their state (running, saved or off) and then starting them or stopping them. That is where I am having trouble.

I tried to pipe it with different commands, but it keeps giving an error which is

> The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either 
>   because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

So what I want is if the machine are running then save them. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You can use an If/Else statement OR a switch statement for this. See the Powershell documentation for examples.

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots. Copy/paste your sample code as text and format it properly.

Comment: I'll try both , Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-3.0) loop and a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-3.0) statement:

```
Get-VM -VMName $name | ForEach-Object {
    switch ($_.State) {
        'running' {
            # do some
        }
        'saved' {
            # do other
        }
        'off' {
            # do something else
        }
        default {
            throw ('Unrecognized state: {0}' -f $_.State)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , That's what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual issue here (shown by the error message) is that `start-vm` doesn't accept pipeline input.  I'm guessing this is the Hyper-V Start-VM cmdlet, by the way.

You could do this to get around the lack of pipeline-aware parameters:

```
Get-VM -VMName $name | where {$_.State -eq $state} | foreach-object {Start-VM -VM $_}
```

Comment: That works as well , Thank you .. as i am new to this , anything interests me and helps me learn how scripting and power shell works .. Appreciate it.

Also yes .. regarding your guess this is hyper-v , but out of curiosity .. are there different cmdlets for different  virtual machine softwares ? 

For example if i need this to work with VM workstation will it function properly or do i need to modify ?

Comment: The VMware module has cmdlets with the same name as some of the Hyper-V cmdlets, but they have different parameters.  You would have to re-work things to use them with that module.

Comment: I understand  , Thank you .